# Register a package service provider from within that package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, service-provider

In all Laravel versions, if we want to register a new service provider, we can open the `config/app.php` file and add the new provider to the `providers` array, like so:

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    Path\To\New\ServiceProvider::class,
],
```

My idea is to install a package and have it automatically load its service provider, so without a need to add the new provider to the Laravel's `app.php`

I have two questions:

1. Is this a good idea? In both cases, why is it good / not good?
2. Is there a preferred way of doing this? My guess is to autoload a bootstrap file from the package's `composer.json`, and then `$this->app->register('Path\To\New\ServiceProvider');` from there.

Is this how it should be done?

As advised by Sven, I'm adding information to clarify what I intend to achieve.

I'm planning to create a core package which would manage adding (installing) and removing its dependant auxiliary packages from a remote repository. For that I would like to have complete autonomy for the auxiliary packages, meaning that 100% of everything related to an auxiliary package should be stored within that package's folder, with an option for users to publish and customize its /resources, as expected in a Laravel app.

Comment: In the Zend framework 2, you also have to enable the modules you want to use, independently of what packages have been added via Composer or manually. This avoids to search all packages for these metadata and makes it explicit which packages should be included as modules, and which other packages only provide additional functions, or should NOT be used even if they'd be able to.

I do prefer stating in code what the developer wants instead of using some automagic. - However, this question is opinion-based and off-topic for stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Sven. I agree that my questions are at least partially opinion-based, but I do believe that they still can be answered objectively. As with virtually any technology, this concept may be abused, but it doesn't make it impossible to use correctly either. My intention is to create a front-end UI from which packages would be enabled/disabled, and for that I need to eliminate the need for users to manually alter any code.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment, if I stop registering package service providers in `config/app.php`, but provide another way of controlling the registered service providers, I don't see any harm done. Also, this has been done previously in many popular packages. I just have doubts about the most recommended way to do it.

Comment: And how does a package get there, before being dynamically registered? And which dependencies does it use, which versions? Even if you'd not go as far as allowing installing new packages, but simply disabling some of the predefined set, this would still be highly dependent on the application at hand. What would "disable" mean? Is it a one-way process? Would "hide it in the menu" be enough?

Comment: Well, answers to your questions probably wouldn't fit in 3-4 comments, plus I fail to see how they would be relevant to my questions. But I'll try to be concise. I'm planning to create a core package which would manage adding (installing) and removing its dependant packages from a remote repository. For that I would like to achieve complete autonomy for the auxiliary packages, meaning that 100% of everything related to an auxiliary package should be stored within that package's folder, with an option for users to publish and customize its `/resources`, as expected in a Laravel app.

Comment: Now this all belongs into your question, and not into a comment.

Comment: I guess you're right. I didn't think all that was relevant. I'll edit my question. Thanks.